# Can I Enable Bulk Endpoints Without RabbitMQ

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm trying to enable bulk endpoints to upload multiple products at once (The CSV uploader seems to be completely broken, so I'm going this route instead).

When I try to enable bulk endpoints **(php bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.operations.all)**, I get a message saying "Unknown connection name amqp".

This seems to be related to **RabbitMQ**, which I can't install because I'm on a cloudways server.

Is there any way around this error, or am I going to have to write some custom functionality to upload my products?

**Magento 2.3.1 CE**

Answer (score 0):

master. I faced the same issue, and the solution I've found was to disable the `async.operations.all` to be queued.
You have to add this to your `app/etc/env.php` file (last array). Magento reference [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/mq/manage-message-queues.html#specific-configuration).

```
...
'cron_consumers_runner' => [
    'cron_run' => false,
    'max_messages' => 20000,
    'consumers' => ['async.operations.all']
],
...
```

In my case, the issue was related to the crontabs, which was getting in conflict with the `flock`.

What I did was: put all the consumers out of cronjob execution. *Note empty array at the `consumers`*:

```
...
'cron_consumers_runner' => [
    'cron_run' => false,
    'max_messages' => 20000,
    'consumers' => []
],
...
```

And then, set one cron for each consumer:

```
* * * * * flock -n /tmp/magento-cron.lock bin/magento cron:run > /dev/null 2>&1;
* * * * * flock -n /tmp/consumer-cron.lock bin/magento queue:consumers:start inventoryQtyCounter > /dev/null 2>&1;
```

Of course, you got to add a crontab for each consumer queue you want to execute, see the [list of consumers queue here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/mq/manage-message-queues.html#view-a-list-of-available-message-queue-consumers).

But I believe, for your case, the first option should work.

Comment: Thanks for responding. When I added that to my list (I had seen that documentation earlier), I get the same error message.
Is there anything else that has to be run afterwards?

Thanks

Comment: Please add this to your `env.php` file:

`...
'cron_consumers_runner' => [
    'cron_run' => false,
    'max_messages' => 20000,
    'consumers' => ['async.operations.all']
],
...`
And do not execute the `bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.operations.all`
The actions will be done without RabbitMQ.

Comment: When I try that, the response message is:  "message": "Unknown connection name amqp"

Comment: Put the consumers' array empty: `'consumers' => []`. It might be necessary to execute the others' queues manually. But do not execute the `async.operations.all`. Let the async process to be done via database.

Comment: I remove the async.operations.all from the array, and my code is now

```
 'cron_consumers_runner' => [
        'cron_run' => false,
        'max_messages' => 1000,
        'consumers' => [
            
        ]
    ]
```

But I still get the message     "message": "Unknown connection name amqp",

Comment: When are you getting this message "Unknown connection name amqp"?
is your cron still running?

Comment: @WillianLevinskiKeller the OP wants Bulk API to work. Neither of your solutions satisfies the question. This answer should be removed as it is misleading others to fix an error message only as opposed to configuring the feature properly.

Comment: @danila-vershinin, wrong!
The topic is asking WITHOUT RabbitMQ. The solution I've proposed is to do not run the consumer queue using cron and then, run the specific queue you want manually.

Comment: @WillianLevinskiKeller You're not reading your own solution? The `'consumers' => ['async.operations.all']` specifies that ONLY `async.operations.all` consumer will run and ONLY externally. You are efficiently disabling/breaking all consumers other than the one that requires RabbitMQ! And "No, only with RabbitMQ" is the answer.

Comment: Note: `'consumers' => []`

Comment: @WillianLevinskiKeller as I've checked the M2 code now, `'consumers' => []` disables consumer from Magento 2 cron's consumer runner, so yes you can run individual consumers by smth else (your own cron). But this doesn't change a fact that you cannot run `async.operations.all` if RabbitMQ is not installed. "Disabling `async.operations.all` from being queued" - solves absolutely nothing other than removing the informational message `Unknown connection name amqp` in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

You *must* install and configure RabbitMQ for the Bulk API feature to work.

Here's a complete [walkthrough for Magento 2 BulkAPI enablement for CentOS/RHEL 7, 8](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/how-to-fix-consumer-async-operations-all-skipped-as-required-connection-amqp-is-not-configured-unknown-connection-name-amqp-in-magento-2).

Essentially, you need to install RabbitMQ and configure `amqp` details in the `app/etc/env.php` to match with the setup, e.g.:

```
    'queue' =>  [
        'amqp' =>  [
            'host' => '127.0.0.1', // IP address of RabbitMQ instance. Change it, if it is not running on the same machine with Magento
            'port' => '5672', // Port on which RabbitMQ running. 5672 is default port
            'user' => 'guest', // RabbitMQ user name
            'password' => 'guest', // RabbitMQ password
            'virtualhost' => '/' // The virtual host for connecting to RabbitMQ. The default is /.
        ],
    ],
```